# Is it possible to send account information when the paid application is purchased?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-play-developer-api

I have a mobile app. This application provides continuous data flow through the server. I want users to log in with their username and password when they purchased my app. How can I send username and password information to the user who bought the app?

1. Is monthly invoicing possible when they buy a paid app on Google play?
2. Can I send username / pass information to the user when my paid app is purchased?

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

By "monthly invoicing" you presumably mean more than just an automatic renewal of a subscription. You can send your own invoices if you like. If you've set up your systems so that you're using the Developer API automatic notifications you will receive notification of subscription renewal when it happens, that could be monthly if that's the subscription period selected. Having received the notification you could then send invoices yourself.

Notice that the more personal details you require from your customers the higher "risk" the Play Store will consider your app to be. This isn't necessarily a problem but it is a consideration.

You can exchange any data you like between your app and your server.

Having said that, the suggestion is that sending account details like that is perhaps a security risk and there are alternative ways of validating. The most useful strategy will depend on the details of your app use, of course.

Comment: The application works with username and password. Users with a username and password can use the application. Is it possible to send this information after payment?

Comment: @BOTBenson, I think I've given you the answer; not only "yes", but also with the mechanism for doing it. Tell me what you don't follow so I can clarify